# nlohmann and copying maps

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

Anyone has idea how to quickly copy `nlohmann::json` MAP values to an other `nlohmann::json`?

```
nlohmann::json j1;
nlohmann::json j2;

j1["MAP"]["value1"] = 1;
j2["MAP"]["value2"] = 2;
j2["MAP"] += j1["MAP"];
```

This will throw because `+=` will think that I am adding a value to a list.

> [json.exception.type_error.308] cannot use push_back() with object

I can enumerate `j1["MAP"]` and add them into `j2["MAP"]` but I was wondering if there is a straightforward method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`json::update()`](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/doxygen/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a377819905d567f6f523dcbc592cb6356.html#a377819905d567f6f523dcbc592cb6356) method is the built-in version of this operation.

```
j2["MAP"].update(j1["MAP"]);
```

Comment: Yay. Thank you. This is what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to @cdhowie 's answer is to **merge** those objects,
here the method that you need: [merge_patch](https://nlohmann.github.io/json/doxygen/classnlohmann_1_1basic__json_a844a77cb154752d12118f10af26d54cb.html#a844a77cb154752d12118f10af26d54cb)

so your code should look like:

```
nlohmann::json j1;
nlohmann::json j2;

j1["MAP"]["value1"] = 1;
j2["MAP"]["value2"] = 2;
//j2["MAP"] += j1["MAP"];

j2.merge_patch(j1);

std::cout << "j2: " << j2.dump().c_str() << std::endl;
```

and will produce a result like this:

```
j2:  {"MAP":{"value1":1,"value2":2}}
```

---

NOTE: even though the result is the same using **update** or **merge_patch** there are some differences in the behavior of those methods: I quote the sir nlohmann, who developed the lib

- JSON Merge Patch (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) is an official standard, whereas update is just a function that combines JSON objects.
- JSON Merge Patch allows to delete, whereas update would change existing values to null.
- Both only work on objects, whereas JSON Patch (https://github.com/nlohmann/json#json-pointer-and-json-patch) works on any JSON type.

so in the end is up to you to choose the method that better fits your applications requirements